# How to use pandas.pivot_table to count number of instances

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to get a count of how many times a store # is referenced by month, but the month column disappears when I include the index.

```
stores_by_month = pd.pivot_table(store by month, values='StoreNo',
                                         index='StoreNo', 
                                         columns='MonthName', 
                                         aggfunc='count')
```

When I delete the index, I get the total count by month only, and it is not broken down by store #.

```
stores_by_month = pd.pivot_table(stores_by_month, values='StoreNo',
                                         columns='MonthName', 
                                         aggfunc='count')
```

I do not want to hardcode month names, because I will be adding new data for future months.

Comment: can you post the dataframe as well, as a dict?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your question with specific details, simplified examples to support your explanation, and code/configuration/links you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest workaround I can find is adding another column to perform the count on. Using data I have on hand that may be similar, I was able to get a count-by-month table this way.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(...) # something with 2 columns

data.loc[:,"DummyCol"] = 1      # doesn't matter what this value is

data.pivot_table(values="DummyCol",index="Col1", columns="Col2", aggfunc='count').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

produces

```
Col2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  11  12
Col1
65065    84  112  222   98  102  125  112   90   95  42  25  40
65139     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   2   0   0
65158     1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0   0   0   0
65165     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0   0   0   0
65192   227  202  408  155   70  151  205  127  142  98  83  73
...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..
80645     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0
80647     0    0    0    0    0    2    4    0    0   0   0   0
80657     0    0    0    6    0    3    1    0    0   0   7   1
80690     1    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   0   1
80702     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   0   0   0
```

Comment: The dataframe only contains two columns, StoreNo and MonthName. I successfully created the pivot table on excel, but I would like to create this pivot table using python.

Comment: @NicoleArdizzi - see my modified answer